# css loading images from a subdomain

Tags: css, image, subdomain

I have a website on https://www.something.com 
Part of the website is on a subdomain https://subdomain.something.com

Id like the website images to only be loaded once throughout the site, therefore on the subdomain images to be loaded from https://www.something.com and if the user has already visited the main site the image wouldn't need to load again, is this possible?

Im thinking this is the only path that can be used, would appreciate it if anyone has any further thoughts on this?

Thanks in advance!

```
background:url("https://www.something.com/images/my-image.png");
```

Comment: Depending on how your subdomain is configured, you may be able to do something like `background:url("/images/my-image.png");` You can test if that works by trying to access your image from `https://www.something.com/images/my-image.png` and `https://subdomain.something.com/images/my-image.png`.

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply, `background:url("/images/my-image.png");` used on the subdomain will find the image on the subdomain, but id like it to find the image on the main domain.

Comment: You may have to use the full url in that case so that the browser knows the image is the same one it has already cached. Is there a reason you'd prefer not to use the full url?

Comment: As I was under the impression, this will mean image would have to load again when the user visited the subdomain? Is this correct?
Thanks again!

Comment: If you use the full url on both parts of the site, the user's browser would normally load the image just once, as the browser can see from the url that that resource is already cached.

Comment: Correct me if im wrong but its not good practice to have the full path (including the https://www.something.com) in the background-image path isit? And also you seem unsure if it would work and the image would only load once when visiting pages on the main site and subdomain.

Comment: Generally the image would only load once using the full url unless your site's code sets a very short expiry date on cached images or the user clears their cache for some reason. Using a full url in your code is generally not the best practice, but there are situations like this where there is no way around it. In those cases, I think it is acceptable to use the full url. Ultimately you need to weight whether it's more important to have one line of code conform to best practices, or to reduce the bandwidth usage of your site.

Answer (score 0):

**Caching**

A cached image is found by it's location it came from. Let's say a user downloads an image via `foo.com` with the source location of the image at `foo.com/image1.jpg`, after that he goes to `subdomain.foo.com` where the same image is displayed. Now if the image is from the same location (`foo.com/image1.jpg`) your browser will notice that and will get the file from your cache. If it's the same image, but from a different source location, your browser won't get it from the cache but will download it instead.

In order to have the image (,css and javascript) in the browsers cache you can put following code in a `.htaccess` file (apache only.)

```
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresDefault "access plus 10 seconds"
ExpiresByType text/html "access plus 10 seconds"
ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 1000000 seconds"
ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1000000 seconds"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1000000 seconds"
ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1000000 seconds"
ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 1000000 seconds"
ExpiresByType text/javascript "access plus 1000000 seconds"
ExpiresByType application/x-javascript "access plus 1000000 seconds"
```

The `1000000 seconds` is the expiration date of the cached file.

If you are able to use a CDN, I would suggest that, because the CDN will  automatically cache static content so you don't have to worry about that. You can put your CDN on your subdomain or you could link to it straight away, but then you might bumb into some cross-domain errors.

**Path**

In your situation, you'll need to use the full path. Because something like this `../images/foo.jpg` will locate the image on the same domain. If, for some reason, you don't want to type the full url for every element you could use PHP.

```
<?php 
    $domain = "http://www.foo.com";
?>

<style>
    div{
        background:url("<?php echo $domain; ?>/images/my-image.png");
    }
</style>
```

note: this piece of code should go in the head tags.